# Using Firebase parameters with Google Cloud Storage under node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, gcloud-node, firebase-storage

There is no node.js Firebase Storage client at the moment (too bad...), so I'm turning to gcloud-node with the parameters found in Firebase's console.

I'm trying :

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var gcloud = require('gcloud')({
    keyFilename: process.env.FB_JSON_PATH,
    projectId: process.env.FB_PROJECT_ID
});

firebase.initializeApp({
    serviceAccount: process.env.FB_JSON_PATH,
    databaseURL: process.env.FB_DATABASE_URL
});

var fb = firebase.database().ref();

var gcs = gcloud.storage();

var bucket = gcs.bucket(process.env.FB_PROJECT_ID);

bucket.exists(function(err, exists) {
    console.log('err', err);
    console.log('exists', exists);
});
```

Where :

- `FB_JSON_PATH` is the path to the JSON file generated in order to use the Firebase Server SDK
- `FB_DATABASE_URL` is something like https://app-a36e5.firebaseio.com/
- `FB_PROJECT_ID` is the name of the firebase project in Google's console : "app-a36e5"

The id of the bucket is `FB_PROJECT_ID` (in Firebase's console the storage tab displays gs://app-a36e5.appspot.com)

When I run this code I get :

```
err null
exists false
```

But no other errors.

I'm expecting `exists true` at least.

Some additional info : I can query the database (so I imagine the JSON file is correct), and I have set the storage rules as follow :

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/app-a36e5.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

So that everything on the storage is readable.

Any ideas how to get it to work ? Thank you.

Comment: Hey Pierre, did you manage to make this work? It would be nice to give a proper answer to this interesting question. Thanks! (Sorry, I did not realize this was only 56min old - let's wait for an answer then :) )

Comment: That said, there is a first issue in your code, you have to call `gcloud.storage` with your credentials: `gcloud.storage({
  projectId: 'firebase-storage-id, keyFilename: 'service-account-json-path'
});`. (I did that but I still have a FORBIDDEN error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you aren't naming your storage bucket correctly. The bucket initialization should be:

```
var bucket = gcs.bucket('app-a36e5.appspot.com'); // full name of the bucket includes the .appspot.com
```

I would assume that `process.env.FB_PROJECT_ID` is just the `your-bucket` part, and you'd need to get the full bucket name, not just the project id (though the bucket name may be `process.env.FB_PROJECT_ID + '.appspot.com'`).

Also, sorry about not providing Storage integrated with Firebase--GCS has a high quality library that you've already found (gcloud-node), and we figured that this provides the best story for developers (Firebase for mobile, Google Cloud Platform for server side development), and didn't want to muddy the waters further.

Comment: The firebase docs are flawless, never had any complaints. The gcloud docs, on the other hand, are pretty confusing. Like Pierre, I just spent hours trying to just upload a file in nodejs. Maybe the correct values for gcloud when using google firebase are unclear. For example, I still don't know what URL to point to the file... some example (GCS) say it's `https://www.googleapis.com/bucket/xxx`,  other (firebase) say its `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/b/bucket/o/xxx`... pretty confusing... (sorry a bit off topic though :) )

Comment: +Pandaiolo if you can put your frustrations with the gcloud-node docs into issue form, it would be great to hear your feedback: https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcloud-common. To start, I created an issue inspired by your feedback here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-common/issues/141

Comment: was that the only edit to the code above required to make this work? I am struggling with the same issue... and I continue to get errors

Comment: This is how I've gotten Firebase Storage to work though GCloud-Node in the past: https://github.com/mcdonamp/flaming-specs/blob/master/function.js